# showing "No module named tweepy" even after installing tweepy. Why?

Tags: python, tweepy

I wanted to do text mining using twitter APIs through tweepy. It installed successfully but when I run my code, it shows

> from tweepy import StreamListener
>    ImportError: No module named tweepy

I wrote the code on atom and using Python 3.7.1. I am on Windows 10.

I wrote the following code for this purpose.

````py
from tweepy import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream

access_token = "********"
access_token_secret = "*************"
consumer_key = "*************"
consumer_secret = "***************"


    def on_data(self, data):
        print data
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status


if __name__ == '__main__':

    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    stream = Stream(auth, l)

    stream.filter(track=['python', 'javascript', 'ruby'])```
````

Comment: The most common explanation I see for cases like this is that you have two versions of Python installed, and you've installed a library into one version but are then using another to run your code.  If you aren't sure, I'd suggest that you check to make sure that this isn't the problem. - I've made this mistake myself multiple times.

Comment: Did you install the package in a virtualenv?

Comment: @Steve seems this is the case. Typing python on my CMD it shows 'Python 3.7.1' but when I type 'python -2' it gives 'Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)|'. I use atom for coding but I have anaconda installed too. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: You can either figure out how to set up your environment to have a particular version of Python be the "current" version, or you can provide a full path to the python executable.  If you run a particular python executable, it will find all of its own environment, like installed packages and everything else.  This is true for both base python installs and virtual environments.  So if you can find the 2.7 binary and use the full path, you'll be sure you're using that version...

Comment: ...the same goes for 'pip'.  To make sure that you're installing to the python version you think you are, run pip via its full path, that path being the same as the path to the python executable of the environment you want to target, but with '/python' replaced with '/pip'

Comment: ...and **which python** should always tell you what the "current" python executable's path is.

Answer (score 0):

You might use different python environments in pycharm as you install pip several times. Try to config the exact python interpreter using the following steps. PyCharm, Settings -> Project Interpreter -> This will show the installed package list and dedicated interpreter at the top right-hand side. Try your right interpreter within the dropdown.
[image]